# Hot to set a background color for the NavigationDrawerFragment in android

Tags: android

i want to know how we can set a background color for the NavigationDrawerFragment in android. There is the code for the element.

PS : i have set the property  `android:background` but its not working.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/connexion_button"
tools:context="com.example.user.unchained.HomesActivity">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/connexion_button"
    android:name="com.example.user.unchained.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: try to change parentView background color of which had been inflated for navigation_drawer fragment

Comment: setbackground color in fragment_navigation_drawer layout or on these listview.

Answer (score 1):

fragment_navigation_drawer.xml

```
   <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/connexion_button"


    >



   </LinerLayout >
```